# Getting path from exported jar not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, path

What I am doing:
I have a piece of code in which I am getting the runnable path and setting it to a label on button click for testing purpose to successfully get the running jar path at runtime.

Problem:
When running through eclipse debug or run mode, I am getting the path in the label but when I export the code to a jar file, nothing is happening on button click.

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TestProject extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    static JLabel lblNewLabel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestProject frame = new TestProject();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TestProject() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                getJarFileRunningPath();

            }
        });
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static String getJarFileRunningPath()
    {
        String currentPath = null;

        try
        {
            File currentFilePath = new File(TestProject.class.getProtectionDomain().
                                    getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());

            currentPath = currentFilePath.getAbsolutePath();


            lblNewLabel.setText(currentPath);
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e)
        {
        }

        return currentPath;
    }

}
```

Update:
I found out somehow that "File currentFilePath = new File..." line is getting stuck, not throwing exception also.

Thanks in future, for any help. :-)

Comment: Did you try remote debugging to see what is actually happening?

Comment: Hi Jim, sorry I don't know remote debugging. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I took your code to check your problem but the code works fine with me.
The generated jar shows me the path in the label.

[image]

I think your problem is not a coding problem.

Comment: Maybe it's something related with the OS version. I'm finding out. :-(